# How to ask "state of the art" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

How can you ask a question, that is intended to give an advice regarding which technologies (software packages, programming languages, etc.) you should use in order to accomplish some tasks?

Because developers could often also need some input about *WHAT* is the 'state of the art' way or technology to accomplish some goals.
Also in order to avoid issues, that result from e.g. using any inappropriate approach.

Comment: Since you are new here: please do not worry about possible down-votes to this question. Votes in  meta do not affect your account or reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't ask that kind of question in Stack Overflow.

They will be closed as primarily opinion based.

Be sure to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thouroughly. If you think a question like that would be on-topic in the site, you may benefit from better familiarzing with our [topicality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Okay thank you, that's it. Is there any stack overflow related site, that features such questions? Like Stack Exchange or something?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Okay, i think, this would be very usefull, but if nothing available okay :)

Comment: Possibly [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read [their FAQ](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jpp Assuming that the question is more or less similar to what the OP describes here, I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be on-topic in SoftRec either. I wouldn't steer users to our sister sites if we are not confident about question quality.

Comment: @yivi, I wouldn't *necessarily* make that assumption. The Meta-question here as it stands isn't an actual StackExchange question. If it was, they should use the "quote" formatting feature with their precise quesetion. Reading the Software Recommendations SE FAQ may encourage the user to reword their requirements for that site.

Comment: It would not be useful because OP's are, in general, hopelessly bad at explaining what their requirements actually are. SO contributors cannot be expected to suggest designs etc,. given the tiny subsection of a full requirement spec that could comfortably fit in an SO question:(